# Differentiable function in terms of partials

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

> Assume $h: \Bbb R ^3 →\Bbb R$ and $g:\Bbb R^2 →\Bbb R$ to be differentiable. We have $F:\Bbb R^2 →\Bbb R$ s.t. $F (x, y) = h (x, y, g(x, y))$. Calculate $DF$ with respect to the partials of $h$ and $g$. If $F(x,y)≡0$ $\forall (x,y)$, then calculate $\frac {\partial g} {\partial x}$,$\frac {\partial g} {\partial y}$ with respect to the partials of $h$.

To find the differential matrix of $F$, it would be a $2\times 3$ matrix I think, and I would have to use the chain rule, but if $F(x,y)=0$ for all $x,y$, then how would I use that information to find the partials of function $g$?

Comment: If you have solved the first part of the problem, then you've got yourself a formula for the partials of $F$ in terms of the partials of $h$ and $g$. Setting $F \equiv 0$, its partials must also vanish, so you immediately obtain an equation relating the partials of $h$ to the partials of $g$. Think implicit function theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, since $F$ maps $\mathbb{R}^2$ into $\mathbb R$, the derivative of $F$ should be a $1\times2$ matrix, that is, a row vector in $\mathbb R^2$. Also, note that if we put $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ given by $f(x,y) = (x,y,g(x,y))$, then $F$ can be written as $h\circ f$. Then, by the Chain Rule,

$$DF(x,y) = (Dh)(f(x,y))Df(x,y) \tag{1}$$

where the right hand side is the product of the matrices

$$(Dh)(f(x,y)) = \Big( \frac{\partial h}{\partial x}(f(x,y)), \frac{\partial h}{\partial y}(f(x,y)), \frac{\partial h}{\partial z}(f(x,y)) \Big)$$

and

$$Df(x,y) = \begin{pmatrix} 1&0 \\ 0&1 \\ \cfrac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x,y) & \cfrac{\partial g}{\partial y}(x,y) \end{pmatrix}$$

while the left hand side of $(1)$ is simply

$$\Big( \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x,y), \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x,y) \Big).$$

Hence, perform the matrix multiplication and match entry by entry to get the partial derivatives of $F$ in term of those of $g$ and $h$.

Finally, if the partial derivatives of $F$ are $0$, you can get the derivatives of $g$ in terms of those of $h$ in the equation obtained above.